# Performance improvement in combining $.css() calls?

Tags: jquery, performance, optimization

For a jQuery app I am maintaining, a recent change I made involved taking code such as this:

```
$someElement.click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $someOverlay.css('left', e.pageX);
  $someOverlay.css('top', e.pageY);
  $someOverlay.fadeIn();
});
```

and revising it to this:

```
$someElement.click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $someOverlay.css({
    'left': e.pageX,
    'top': e.pageY
  });

  $someOverlay.fadeIn();
});
```

I made that change upon discovering that one can simply pass an object to the `$.css()` method.  Of course, as I am wont to do, I got to thinking about the performance effects of this.  It seems to me that calling `$.css()` once would be more efficient than making two `$.css()` calls...but, this is also JavaScript, which is a language I am not as versed in as, say, C#.

So, **Question:** which code above is a more performant way of applying some CSS to an element?

Comment: You are working on the client side. You are using the client's pc to do this task. If he is using a desktop pc, his specs are orders of magnitude above the minimum required for any task you can throw at it.
Performance matters on the server side, on embedded systems and on mobile / low spec systems. Certainly not something to lose working time on in a webpage

Comment: It's not something I'm agonizing over, I was merely curious so that, going forward, I can code in the most optimal way (depending of course on circumstances.)  This isn't a 'lose working time' question rather than a 'best practices' question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First answer: It almost certainly doesn't matter.

Second answer: If you walk through the jQuery `css` method (which is no mean feat!), you'll find that it's probably more efficient to use the combined form (passing in a spec object).

Comment: Why is it that you say it almost certainly dosen't matter?

Comment: @AndrewGray: Because unless you're doing this 100,000 times in a tight loop while the user waits (in which case, you probably have other issues), there will be no real-world, perceptible difference between them.

Comment: @AndrewGray - cause you'll probably never notice the difference. If T.J. would give us an example of `element.style`, that would probably be the greatest improvement you could do, but you'll probably never notice the difference on that either ?

Comment: @adeneo: Probably not.  I only have this occurring on a click event, and even then, this isn't a click that is spammable.  The question came out of sheer curiosity.  (Also, 'just in case' I have to worry with a spammable CSS change on a specific element.)

Answer (score 1):

The second variant is described as good parctice [here](http://josefaeti.com/articles/2011/July/jquery-best-practices-for-better-performance-and-speed.html#object-literals), so I think the performance will be better.

```
// passing object literals as parameters is good practice

var $foo = $( '#foo' );

$foo.css({
  'color': 'red',
  'width': '200px',
  'height': '200px'
});
```